# Format and beautify Java code while typing in textarea of html

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea in my webpage works as a editor. 
While typing the java/c/c++ code in the textarea, I want the code to be formatted and auto beautify itself (like coloring keywords, spaces, auto tabs for code inside {} blocks).

Or

I need an editor which can be embedded in my webpage.

Comment: Note that an HTML based text area will not show nicely colored code like we see on SO.  It does not support such abilities.

Comment: Yes, Html textarea doesn't support. That is why I am asking for libraries. 
And the answer is CodeMirror.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CodeMirror (C, C++ and Java example there : http://codemirror.net/mode/clike/index.html)

It's really simple to make it work, just include codemirror.js, codemirror.css and the .js of the languages you want in your page's header, then there is a method to create an editor from a textarea, for instance :

```
CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("TEXTAREA_ID"), {
  mode:  "text/x-java",
  indentWithTabs: true,
  smartIndent: true,
  lineNumbers: true,
  lineWrapping: true,
  matchBrackets : true,
  autofocus: true
});
```

More infos : http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html

Of course there are others (Ace, EditArea, ...) but I already used that one and I'm happy with it :)

Cheers